# Can I filter out my traffic in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, web-traffic

I have a site running Google analytics and I end up being a large fraction of the traffic to it (like 1 of the 2 hits per day). Is there any way I can set it so that my browsing doesn't skew the numbers so much? I'd be happy if it just didn't record anything for accesses that are logged in as my Google account.

Comment: HOw do you end up being a large fraction? Can you give more infor about your site?

Comment: there is very little traffic to begin with <G>

Comment: how would this work for Google Sites if you have a dynamic IP address? As far as I know you cannot add custom JavaScript - is there a known solution to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Filter Manager in your analytics settings

http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55481&cbid=-1j8it19c4uzvt&src=cb&lev=answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use filter to exclude

1. Traffic from a a domain
2. IP address
3. Sub directory

or you can use a custom filter. You can edit your site to set a campaign code if **you** login in and use the custom filter to exclude that campaign code.

You can also try out the ip filter if you use the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use an [ad blocking](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865) or [javascript disabling](http://noscript.net/) extension in your browser to prevent google analytics from being loaded.

Comment: to whoever voted this down. It's a perfectly legitimate option. I run the noscript extension in FF and it would take me literally a few seconds to block analytics for just my site. That's less time than it would take to log in and configure analytics.

Comment: voted down again?? who are these idiots? This answer is perfectly applicable to the question asked. Explain yourself.

Comment: This way all the clients visiting the site have to install extensions in their browser instead of setting the proper filters only once.

Comment: This is an extremely impractical solution. If the site contains other js components (which is very likely these days), then the author will likely want to see and use these as part of the site's functionality. Disabling it completely on the client side only to accomplish something that can and should be set in the analytics configuration is silly. If you want to use ad blocking or js blocking extensions, that's great, but isn't really applicable to this situation realistically.

Comment: It's very easy to target adblock or noscript at google analytics specifically, without affecting other JS components.

Answer (score 1):

A neat solution is to simply stop the tracking javascript from being sent to the browser based on a cookie set on your machine. This can be done by simply adding a few lines of code to your page. Take a look at [this article](http://www.sonix-media.com/blog/web-development/how-to-filter-out-your-own-traffic-in-google-analytics/) for a full explaination.

Comment: +1 but I can't use that as I only have access to a static template.

Comment: The best option for staic pages will be to use Google's blocking cookie method.

Answer (score 0):

If you login there logged in as a site user, maybe you basing on this you just do not put the JavaScript for Google Analytics in the output HTML. This is a typical case when you are an administrator and you do not want to mess the results basing on your activities.

If you are able to touch the code that runs your site I think this is the simplest way to go.

If it is not the case, please provide some more details.